# Sending a File from a Python script to a PHP Script using POST deployed on Xampp Server

Tags: php, python

I am trying to send a file (may be txt, pdf, xls or docx) from my python script to PHP script. I deployed on XAMPP server. SO far I have tried several methods, but no luck. This my python script im using to send a file:

```
url = 'http://192.168.1.8:80/testFile.php'
files = {'file': open('expected.txt', 'rb')}
r= requests.post(url, files=files)
```

I have also tried the `urllib`:

```
f=open(filename, 'rb')
filebody = f.read()
f.close()
data = {'name':'file','file': filebody}
u = urllib.urlopen(url,urllib.urlencode(data))
print u.read().
```

Both are giving the same error

> Undefined index: fileToUpload in **C:\xampp\htdocs\testFile.php**
>   on line **16**

This is the php code I posted on the other end to receive file from python script

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
```